# Query With Date Ranges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, date

I have a stored procedure that I want to 1st gather data between a `@startdate` & `@enddate` then I want to compare that data to the previous year.

I tried the below syntax (for testing obviously) to ensure I was getting my desired dates output before I added to my production syntax.  However, this gives me an error of

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near '–'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near '–'.

This is the syntax I tried.  What would I alter in order for my required dates to be output?

```
Declare @startdate date = '20170101'
    ,@enddate date = '20170212'

--one year prior to @startdate
Select CAST(DateAdd(yy, -1, @startdate) As Date)

--One year prior to @enddate
SELECT CAST(DateAdd(yy, -1, @enddate) As Date)

--This will get first day of prev yr
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,
        DATEADD(YEAR, –1, @startdate)), 0)

--This will get last day of prev yr
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, –3, DATEADD(YEAR,
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, –1, @enddate)) + 1, 0))
```

**EDIT**
What I want to return is

```
01/01/2017
02/12/2017
01/01/2016
12/31/2016
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure where you copied this code from, but it looks like it came from a web site that translated minus signs (`-`) to long dashes (`–`). You can see this in Management Studio if you turn IntelliSense on:

> [image]

Here is the easy way to compare the same range as the year before:

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '20170101',
        @enddate   date = '20170212';

SELECT @startdate, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @startdate),
       @enddate,   DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @enddate);
```

*This compares the same period as last year, but I'm not sure that's what you're after since you are also using the zero date and `datediff` - not clear why. It does not account for leap year; you'll need to define what should happen if the range involves 2/29 either this year or last year.*

When you use those dates in a query, don't do this subtracting 3 milliseconds nonsense - it only leads to problems. If you're trying to get all the data for February 12th even if it has time, then use `< DATEADD(DAY, 1, @enddate)`. Also, don't use `YY`, just type out `YEAR`. It is also far easier to get the full range of last year:

```
-- for SQL Server 2012+
WHERE col >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@startdate)-1, 1, 1)
  AND col <  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@startdate), 1, 1);

-- for older, unsupported versions:
WHERE col >= DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(@startdate)-1901, '19000101'),
  AND col <  DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(@startdate)-1900, '19000101');
```

To sum up:

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '20170101',
        @enddate   date = '20170212';

-- sales from that period this year:

SELECT SUM(some_column) FROM dbo.SomeTable
  WHERE some_datetime_column >= @startdate
    AND some_datetime_column <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @enddate);

-- sales from same period previous year (again, not accounting for leap special case):

SELECT SUM(some_column) FROM dbo.SomeTable
  WHERE some_datetime_column >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @startdate)
    AND some_datetime_column <  DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @enddate));

-- sales from all of previous year:

SELECT SUM(some_column) FROM dbo.SomeTable
  WHERE some_datetime_column >= DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(@startdate)-1901, '19000101'),
    AND some_datetime_column <  DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(@startdate)-1900, '19000101');
```

Suggested reading:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- [#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly)